# Weird result of using CTE

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

Could somebody explain me why this script returns `'some_word'` but not error about not existed schema trying to retrieve data from `schema_that_doesnt_exist.tab`?

```
with tab as 
(
     select 'some_word' str 
     from dual
)
select * 
from schema_that_doesnt_exist.tab;
```

Some URL on Oracle documentation about this question will help me too.

Comment: I think it definitely gives error if that table and schema not exists

Comment: Did you run that whole query or part of subquery of dual

Comment: Yes, I did. And there is no error.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the schema doesn't exist, or if the schema does exist but it doesn't have a table `tab` in it; in both cases, the query will use the CTE instead. I don't know why this is, and I haven't seen anything about it here or on OTN. It surely looks like a bug to me. With that said: a bug is only defined with reference to "intended behavior". It is possible (even likely) that Oracle will claim this is no bug, but instead the behavior is as intended. WHY they would intend this behavior is unclear; I would call bs on it if this was their answer.

Comment: @Rams - you tell us what you "think", and you ask the OP if she tested it. Did **you** test it before challenging the OP? It's very easy to test it and to understand what the OP is reporting.

Comment: @mathquy - thank you. I'd like to add that if schema does exist and it has a table TAB the result will be the same as it wouldn't have a table TAB.

Comment: @mathguy I just tested it in db2 so I got error that is why I asked him to check it, at present I dont have oracle db to test it

Comment: @Rams - so what is the concern - that there aren't enough people on SO who know and have access to Oracle to help the OP? The question is clearly tagged Oracle.

Comment: @mathguy I know it is for oracle and I didnt say that there aren't enough people but I tried in db2( most of the syntax is similar)  and just asked OP, I didnt confirm but just asked

Comment: @Rams Could you check it on DB2 LUW?

Comment: Another good reason to avoid schema names in queries.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it has connection with [qualified names bypass with](https://modern-sql.com/feature/with#compatibility):

[MariaDB Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ffb6d2f2d493c8dbcf0e070388b1aa45)

[Oracle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ffb6d2f2d493c8dbcf0e070388b1aa45)

[SQLite Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=f8284039b52319fc31077cbb82b3bdae)     -- no such table: schema_that_doesnt_exists.tab

[PostgreSQL Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f8284039b52319fc31077cbb82b3bdae)     -- relation "schema_that_doesnt_exists.tab" does not exist

[SQLServer Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f8284039b52319fc31077cbb82b3bdae) -- Invalid object name 'schema_that_doesnt_exists.tab'.

---

Same as:

[image]

<sup>Image from: https://modern-sql.com/blog/2018-04/mysql-8.0</sup>

Anyway it could be useful when you need to mock some data for database unit tests (read only queries).

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM schema.table_name  -- here goes real data (lots of records)
WHERE col = 'sth';
```

If I want to prepare input dataset for test I have to work with actual data.
Using `WITH` I could rewrite it as:

```
WITH table_name AS (
    SELECT 'sth'  AS col, ... FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'sth2' AS col, ... FROM dual...
)
SELECT *
FROM schema.table_name  -- cte is closer and data is taken from it
WHERE col = 'sth';
```

More: [Unit Tests on Transient Data](https://modern-sql.com/use-case/unit-tests-on-transient-data)